# How Heroku SendGrid add-on billing system work

Tags: heroku, sendgrid

When I try to add [Heroku SendGrid Addon - Starter Plan](https://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid), I accidentally click "Add SendGrid Platinum Plan Addon" button. I didn't get any confirmation and add-on is added to my application automatically. I refresh my browser immediately and removed the Heroku app.

Will I be charged monthly fee for SendGrid Platinum plan? Since I deleted my application, I could not check whether SendGrid account for that old application is still active or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anything you will probably be up for a few cents depending on how long you ran the addon for, but you will not be charged the full fee.

Heroku state the following within their documentation:

> Databases and add-ons are prorated to the second based on their applicable monthly fee.

which means that you are only charged for the time that is used. For example, if you use it for 10% of the month, you are up for ~$40.

**Source**: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Rhys Elsmore. Allow me to vote up once I have enough reputation. I just start using this site.